# Disable sound effects on Spinner

Tags: android

I have to disable the "click" sound on all my interface, but I can't get it to work on Spinner items. No matter what I do, I always get the sound when I select a item on a Spinner:

That's what I tried:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/selecao_ordem"
   ***
   android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```

My spinner item:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```

And on Java code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.selecao_ordem_opts));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    selecao_ordem.setAdapter(adapter);
    selecao_ordem.setSelection(opcoes.ordem);
    selecao_ordem.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Haptic Feedback switched on?

Comment: What Haptic Feedback has to do with this? The soundEffectsEnabled="false" is working on all other elements on my interface (buttons, imageViews) that are clickable, I'm only having problem with this one

Comment: By the way, I disabled Haptic Feedback on system settings, and the sound continues on this particular component

Comment: Are you working with Stock Android or something like HTC Sense?

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy Tab. Unfortunately I don't have a sock android device to test it

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be due to this. Try it on an emulator?